# What are the consequences of not keeping Sarissa's secret?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

During Cora's loyalty mission you go off in search of the Asari ark, the Leusinia. After finding the ark and working your way through the mission within you find out a dirty little secret of the Asari pathfinder, Sarissa.

What are the consequences of not keeping Sarissa's secret?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you decide to reveal the secret, you will get another decision allowing you to replace her with Vederia, or to support her continuing to serve as the Asari pathfinder. So, we're dealing with three possibilities here: keep the secret, reveal the secret but keep Sarissa, or reveal the secret and choose Vederia as pathfinder:

#### Don't Reveal

[Kalina](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/52800/kalina) has reported on what happens if you keep the secret:

> If you choose to keep the secret you'll still confront Sarissa so she'll know that you know but she is now under the understanding that you're keeping the secret for the greater good and to keep hope alive. Cora will have many conversations with you about the decision and depending on the choices made gets over it and moves on. With this choice Sarissa turns up during the final priority mission to provide additional fire support during the main push.

#### Reveal and Keep Sarissa

This is what I did on my only playthrough so far.

This resulted in a significant amount of dialog with Cora, not only on the Asari ark but in further conversations aboard the Tempest and in Pathfinder HQ. Cora was conflicted about the decision, but not angry with me. Based on Kalina's description, it sounds like, although the exact words might change, this is basically the same as keeping the secret.

Sarissa can be found in Pathfinder HQ.

[l I](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3917/l-i) indicates that she will show up in the final mission.

#### Reveal and Choose Vederia

[According to Polygon](http://www.polygon.com/mass-effect-andromeda-guide-walkthrough/2017/3/24/15049512/cora-loyalty-asari-ark-at-dutys-edge-duty-calls-a-foundation-periphona-leusinia-vederia-sarissa),

> Your decision only effects which asari shows up to help you during the end of the game.

Which implies that if you choose Vederia she will show up to aid you in the final mission. It also corroborates our two user reports indicating that Sarissa aids you in the final mission in both the other options.

Comment: Fyi Sarissa shows up regardless whether or not you revealed her secret or not as long as you keep her.  I revealed her secret and kept her and she showed up at the final mission

Comment: Re Cora's behavior in choice 3: IIRC her reaction is broadly similar to the first two.  She does not get angry at Ryder, but is quite pissed off at Sarissa.  Obviously the precise subject matter will be different from choices 1 and 2, but I'm pretty sure she ends up feeling conflicted no matter what choice you make.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep Sarissa's secret or make Vederia the new Pathfinder, they will help you save Captain Dunn.

If you disgrace Sarissa but allow her to keep her Pathfinder title, you have to later find her and apologise for telling the secret, otherwise she will not contribute to the rescue and Captain Dunn will die. This is the only substantial long-term consequence.

Comment: Where can you find her later on?

Answer (score -2):

I first chose to reveal the secret but keep Sarissa. She helped in the final mission, but captain Dunn did, in fact, die. Subsequent playthroughs, I have chosen vederia, and captain Dunn has been saved.

Comment: captain dunn died because not all the pathfinders showed up, not because you kept sarissa, she survived in my game

Comment: I had 3 pathfinders :( Sarissa, Hayjer, Rix.

Comment: and did they all show up at the final battle?